# Conversion from NSString to int not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created an a nsstring idd variable in .h. and synthesized in .m. Now i have an int variable b and want to store the value of idd in b. Now when i convert idd to int. it not working the b always give me the 0 value.

.h

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *idd;
```

.m

```
 int b=[idd intValue];
NSLog(@"the value of b=%d",b);
```

Comment: if `idd` is null, `b` will be `0`

Comment: When does idd get a value?

Comment: You're setting your string as an outlet...?

Comment: That code won't even compile unless you either `synthesize` idd (which you don't specify) or you use `self.idd`. You also don't supply the results of your NSLog along with the incoming value of idd.

Comment: what is the string you'd like to convert to `int`? a `nil` pointer? a regular text or what? and why do you set it as `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBOutlets and IBActions are macros that mark variables and methods that can be referred to by Interface Builder to link UI elements to your code. They're typically linked to subclasses of NSResponder (like NSButton, NSView, etc.); not NSString's. Unless idd is bound to something in a NIB it won't have any value other than the default (zero). If idd is bound to a GUI object (control) then what you probably want is that controls value (in which case your code is correct).

Answer (score 1):

`idd` probably doesn't have a value, or has a value that can't be parsed into an integer. Try `NSLog`ing `idd` to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
idd = @"2";
int b = [idd intValue];
NSLog(@"b = %i", b);
```

and that should display 2 as b

Answer (score 0):

You need

`int b=[self.idd intValue];`